# 403 forbidden when I try to post to my spring api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Using postman, I can get a list of users with a get request to:  `http://localhost:8080/users`.

But when I send a post request to the same address, I get a 403 error.

```
@RestController
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> retrievaAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }


        @PostMapping("/users")
        public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
            User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

            URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
                    .path("/{id}")
                    .buildAndExpand(savedUser.getId())
                    .toUri();

            return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

        }


    }


@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /*@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }*/


    /*@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }*/
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // TODO which cna be removed

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(Long id, String name, String password, Role role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}





    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {


    }






INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, 'user1', 'pass1', 'ADMIN'); 
INSERT INTO user VALUES (2, 'user2', 'pass2', 'USER'); 
INSERT INTO user VALUES (3,'user3', 'pass3', 'ADMIN')
```

EDIT

[image]

[image]

EDit 2

added delete, but it also gives a 403?

```
@DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
```

public void deleteUser(@PathVariable long id) {
    userRepository.deleteById(id);
}

[image]

edit 4

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll();

        }
    }



@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


}
```

Comment: Postman does some tricky stuff to make itself work sometimes.  Have you compared the headers in each request to see if there are any differences?

Comment: is there any stacktrace like `Access is denied` or something ?

Comment: @benjaminc i don't see any, and I've disabled authrozation, so don't know why there would be any?

Comment: @ab11 since `@EnableWebSecurity` is used, try disabling csrf support `.csrf().disable()`

Comment: @drowny you're right, it worked when I added `.and().csrf().disable();`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`@EnableWebSecurity` enables spring security and it by default enables `csrf` support, you must disable it in order to prevent 403 errors.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
     http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Or send `csrf` token with each request.

**Note: disabling `csrf` makes application less secure, best thing to do is send `csrf` token.**

Comment: thanks, but how can i send csrf token to api? i know that in html page tag form we use `th:action="@{url}"`, but when we use api we directely access the restcontroller methods.

Answer (score 6):

When you use spring boot with spring security and if you are accessing your API's(POST, PUT, DELETE) from Postman or something, they wont be accessible and error is related to authorization like forbidden 403.

So in that case, you have to disabled to csrf functionality to run and test the API from Postman.

The answer provided by @benjamin c is right. You have to add the class with the this configuration will work.

Make sure you are removing this when you add your code in production. CSRF protection is must and you have to keep it in security functionality.

I am just extending his answer for more details by providing complete class details. My requirement was to just test the API from Postman, so I added this class, and able to test the API from Postman.

But after that I have added Spring Junit classes to test my functionalities and removed this class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
}
```

Hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 3):

403 means you don't have authorization. Even though you commented out your method, your code will still be preconfigured with default security access.

You can add:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll();
```

UPDATE : The configuration with csrf disabled:

```
http.csrf()
     .ignoringAntMatchers("/users/**")
     .and()
     .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/users/**").permitAll();
```

Comment: thanks, I've updated my SecruityConfig, but get the same 403 on delete and create. please see my latest edit with my new SecurityConfig. Could it relate to the Application class? I included it's source as well

Comment: add also http.csrf().disable(); also from your screenshots you are trying to post a list of users and in your method you have only one user.

Answer (score 3):

This configuration in SecurityConfig class helped me solve it:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please configure your http like this ;

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        //configureothers if u wants.
        .csrf().disable();
}
```

Please read for more [CSRF](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/)